fastapi Path examples are generated in the wrong openapi location
fastapi version : 0.109.2
pydantic version : 2.7.0
This is the code :
def get_assessment(
    gr_id: str = Path(description="the id of the global ready assessment", examples={"gr0": {"value": "GR0"}, "gr1": {"value": "GR1"}}), settings: Settings = Depends(get_settings)
) -> Assessment:
    return assessment_service.get_assessement_by_id(gr_id)

is generating this openapi yaml :
      parameters:
        - name: gr_id
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            title: Gr Id,
            description: the id of the global ready assessment
            examples:
              gr0:
                value: GR0
              gr1:
                value: GR1
          description: the id of the global ready assessment

you can see that the examples attribute is misplaced. I should not be inside the schema attribute but at the same level, something like that :
      parameters:
        - name: gr_id
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            title: Gr Id
          examples:
            gr0:
              value: GR0
            gr1:
              value: GR1
          description: the id of the global ready assessment

I don't figure out how do obtain this yaml.
From what I understand, there is some openapi extension capabilities in fastapi (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/how-to/extending-openapi/). I would like to keep it simple in order to not have too much code related to openapi, dispatched in too many files.
I also tried to use openapi_examples (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example/)
EDIT 1 : (I also tried to use openapi_examples)
code :
def get_assessment(
    gr_id: str = Path(description="the id of the global ready assessment", openapi_examples={"gr0": {"value": "GR0"}, "gr2": {"value": "GR1"}}), settings: Settings = Depends(get_settings)
) -> Assessment:
    return assessment_service.get_assessement_by_id(gr_id)

result : it just changes the attribute name examples becomes openapi_examples
      parameters:
        - name: gr_id
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            title: Gr Id,
            description: the id of the global ready assessment
            openapi_examples:
              gr0:
                value: GR0
              gr1:
                value: GR1
          description: the id of the global ready assessment

EDIT 2 : (SOLVED)
In fact I was using fastapi-0.100.1
after a poetry update the version is 0.109.3 and the openapi is correctly generated !

"i also tried to use openapi_examples" -- How did you try to use openapi_examples and what effect did it have? From the FastAPI code and docs it looks like openapi_examples is the correct keyword for parameter-level examples (i.e. should produce the 2nd YAML), whereas examples are for schema-level examples as in the 1st YAML.

@Helen, i edited the original post with the result of openapi_examples usage

openapi_examples works fine for me in FastAPI 0.111 with this code. Generated JSON. Is it possible that you actually use FastAPI <= 0.102 which didn't support openapi_examples?

@Helen you were right. Despite my .toml mentionning fastapi = "~0.109.1" i was using the version 0.100.1.
after a poetry update, the version is 0.109.3 and the openapi is correctly generated.
Thank you for your help. I updated the post
